# How can I integrate Twitter API v1.1 in Android using Eclipse to login in Twitter?

Tags: android, eclipse, twitter

I have seen a lot of tutorials (and the official docs included) that show how to archive this by using Android Studio, wich is the new officially supported platform, deprecating Eclipse.

I have tried installing Fabric plugin but it throws me a lot of errors of Java Compliance Level. That tell me that I am doing something wrong. Please, some help would be very apreciated!

Comment: This will seem like the wrong answer, but use android studio...Android studio is so much better than Eclipse in every way and has easy support for Twitter. (It took me a few minutes to get it all setup!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) on eclipse, you can import the lib from maven if it's necesary

Comment: @Agustin Zanini Approach anything officially it might be not easier comparatively but for quality you have to follow it..